# How does golang run smart type assertion in runtime?

Tags: go

I am trying to make sure of the interface to do runtime type assertation

```
type Worker interface {
}

type WorkerA struct {
    x int
    Worker
}

type WorkerB struct {
    WorkerA
}

type Team struct {
    wk Worker // I use the interface instead of specific struct for "polymorphism"
}

// here I use the type switch and assertion to find the right type so to access the members of the struct
func (t *Team)Get() {
    switch t.wk.(type) {
    case *WorkerA:
        {
            e := t.wk.(*WorkerA)
            fmt.Println(e.x)
        }
    case *WorkerB:
        {
            e := t.wk.(*WorkerB)
            fmt.Println(e.x)
        }
    }
}

func test() {
    A := WorkerA{x:145}
    T := Team{wk:&A}
    T.Get()
    B := WorkerB{WorkerA{x:15}}
    T = Team{wk:&B}
    T.Get()
}
```

it works well by running the `test()` so far. In my project, I need to extend the concept to have WorkerA, WorkerB, WorkerB ... up to 250 different structures (all with WorkerA embedded though), and I may have to pass the code to a third party team for after development and thus using a switch type not very convenient. Is it any smart way to auto-match the type in golang like

```
func (t *Team)Get()
    e := t.wk.(t.wk.type)
    fmt.Println(e.x)
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems very unlikely that having 250 distinct type implementations of the same interface is a sane design choice. There are probably other patterns you can leverage to make this more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

```golang
e := t.wk.(t.wk.type)
```

This pseudo-statement is completely meaningless because Go is statically typed.  Doing a type assertion to a type, when you don't know what that type is, is just completely illogical and contrary to the very idea of a type assertion.

I think you need to utilize your `Worker` interface better.  The purpose of interfaces, after all, is to express common behaviour.  If you want to be able to get the `x` field from any `Worker` you can express that in the interface like so:

```golang
type Worker interface {
    GetX() int
}
```

Then, implement this method in your `Worker` types:

```golang
type WorkerA struct {
    x int
    Worker
}

func (w *WorkerA) GetX() int {
    return w.x
}
```

Since your type `WorkerB` embeds `WorkerA`, it will automatically gain this method, and both types will now satisfy the `Worker` interface.

Now your simplified `Get` method looks like this:

```golang
func (t *Team)Get() {
    fmt.Println(t.wk.GetX())
}
```

Comment: worth noting: having a field and a method with the exact same names won't work. Use `.getX()` or something similar for the getter method.

Comment: @LeGEC good point.  I've updated the answer